# SQL division by 0 Error

Tags: sql

Hi guys I have this code that I wrote and I cannot get it to work for some reason

```
round(count(distinct customer)*100.0 /Total_Customer_pop, 2)||'%' as Customer_Signup_Rate
```

I've tried the `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` with no luck

```
ISNULL(round(count(distinct customer)*100.0 /NULLIF(Total_Customer_pop, 2),0))||'%' as Customer_Signup_Rate
```

Is there something I'm not seeing or am I doing my calculation wrong?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to use `NULLIF(Total_Customer_pop, 0)` so the denominator returns `NULL` if it's `0`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Depending on that, different null checks are used...

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up the arguments for `round()` and `nullif()`.  Just focusing on the denominator:

```
NULLIF(Total_Customer_pop, 0), 2))||'%' as Customer_Signup_Rate
```

I would advise you to get the *calculations* correct in SQL.  Leave the formatting of numbers and percentage signs to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
ISNULL(round(count(distinct customer)*100.0 
/ISNULL(NULLIF(Total_Customer_pop, 0), 2),0))||'%' 
as Customer_Signup_Rate
```

Have in mind that i guess you want if it is 0 to use 2.